# Calibração de câmera estereo através do tabuleiro de xadrez em openCV

Tags: python, opencv

Estou tentando realizar a calibração de uma câmera estereo utilizando o openCV, porém a função findChessboardCorners sempre está retornando False, acredito que seja em funçâo da alta distorção da imagem. Alguma sugestão de pré-processamento para tornar a função acertiva?

Exemplo do código:

```
# Encontre as Bordas do tabuleiro
ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(img, (5, 4),cv2.CALIB_CB_ASYMMETRIC_GRID)
```

Exemplo das imagens:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Oi, tudo bem? Dê uma olhada neste vídeo que pode te ajudar: [OpenCV image distortion and rectification](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=otVW4UzSK8w) Na descrição há um link para o código.
Esse: [GitHub Code](https://github.com/lucasw/vimjay/blob/master/src/standalone/distort_image.cpp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com `ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(img, (5, 4),cv2.CALIB_CB_ASYMMETRIC_GRID)`, você está utilizando a matriz de padrão `(5, 4)`.

Mas se observar no tabuleiro de xadrez impresso, a folha de padrão é `(7, 9)` e 20 mm x 20 mm.

Então utilizando o [tutorial oficial de Calibração](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html), o seguinte código é criado:

### Código

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import glob

# Dimensões do Tabuleiro de Xadrez
cbcol = 7
cbrow = 9
cbw = 20

# Critério
criteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, cbw, 0.001)


# preparar os pontos do objeto, como (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((cbrow * cbcol, 3), np.float32)
objp[:, :2] = np.mgrid[0:cbcol, 0:cbrow].T.reshape(-1, 2)
# Vetores para armazenar os pontos de objeto e pontos de imagem de todas as imagens.
objpoints = [] # ponto 3d no espaço do mundo real
imgpoints = [] # ponto 2d no plano da imagem.
images = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\teste\\calib\\*.jpg')
i=0
for fname in images:
    print(fname)
    img = cv.imread(fname)
    gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Encontra os cantos do tabuleiro de xadrez
    ret, corners = cv.findChessboardCorners(gray, (cbcol,cbrow), None)
    # Se encontrado, adiciona os pontos de objeto e pontos de imagem (após refiná-los)
    print(ret)
    if ret == True:
        objpoints.append(objp)
        corners2 = cv.cornerSubPix(gray,corners, (11,11), (-1,-1), criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners)
        # Desenha e mostra os cantos
        cv.drawChessboardCorners(img, (cbcol, cbrow), corners2, ret)
        cv.imwrite('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\teste\\calib\\resultado\\' + str(i) + '.jpg', img)
        cv.imshow('img', img)
        cv.waitKey(500)
        i += 1
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

### Resultados

[image: Resultado 0]

[image: Resultado 1]

[image: Resultado 2]

> Lembrando que o tutorial oficial pede pelo menos 10 fotos para
>   realizar uma calibração confiável. Ou [este problema](http://answers.opencv.org/question/28438/undistortion-at-far-edges-of-image/?answer=29424#post-id-29424) pode ocorrer.

### Calibrar Câmera

Após encontrar os pontos, a calibração pode ser realizada:

`ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)`

### Criar nova matriz da câmera

```
h,  w = img.shape[:2]
newcameramtx, roi = cv.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx, dist, (w,h), 1, (w,h))
```

### Imagem não distorcida

Há dois métodos de realizar isso, o primeiro utiliza a função do OpenCV `undistort()` e o segundo a função OpenCV `remap()`

#### undistort()

```
dst = cv.undistort(img, mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx)
# crop the image
x, y, w, h = roi
dst = dst[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv.imwrite('calibresult.png', dst)
```

#### remap()

```
mapx, mapy = cv.initUndistortRectifyMap(mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx, (w,h), 5)
dst = cv.remap(img, mapx, mapy, cv.INTER_LINEAR)
# crop the image
x, y, w, h = roi
dst = dst[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv.imwrite('calibresult.png', dst)
```

Comment: Olá @danieltakeshi, sua resposta me ajudou muito. Obrigado pela colaboração.